# How to use Angular Bootstrap in MVC5?

Tags: angularjs

Try to use the "Tab" features build by the Angular & Bootstrap
I download the latest script for both Angular Angular-UI Bootstrap and link the bootstrap.css to my page
However it still doesn't load the correct output> Do I still need initiate the Angular ng-controller?
Anyone can help here is my code. 
Here is the source script code

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

HTML Code

```
     <div ng-app ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
      <tabset justified="true">
        <tab heading="Justified">Justified content</tab>
        <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
        <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
       </tabset>
      </div>
```

Bottom script excute code

```
 <script>
  var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
     $scope.tabs = [
       { title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1' },
       { title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
     ];

     $scope.alertMe = function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
             alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
         });
     };
 };
 </script>
```

Let me know if i still need this to wrap the execute script up

```
        angular.module('detailapp', [])
        .controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

       });
```

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:51491/House/Details/template/tabs/tab.html 404 (Not Found)       angular.js:8980
 (anonymous function) angular.js:8980
  sendReq angular.js:8766
 $http.serverRequest angular.js:8486
  processQueue angular.js:12018
  (anonymous function) angular.js:12034
   Scope.$eval angular.js:13202
    Scope.$digest angular.js:13014
    Scope.$apply angular.js:13306
       bootstrapApply angular.js:1499
         invoke angular.js:4099
           doBootstrap angular.js:1497
        bootstrap angular.js:1517
        angularInit angular.js:1411
        (anonymous function) angular.js:24258
        l jquery?v=EEZBCVzQe1TpkEUeLfjEm53wpuqSSXGjiXFWAVaewp81:1
        s.fireWith jquery?v=EEZBCVzQe1TpkEUeLfjEm53wpuqSSXGjiXFWAVaewp81:1
        i.extend.ready jquery?v=EEZBCVzQe1TpkEUeLfjEm53wpuqSSXGjiXFWAVaewp81:1
        a jquery?v=EEZBCVzQe1TpkEUeLfjEm53wpuqSSXGjiXFWAVaewp81:1
        Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/tabs/tab.html
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/$compile/tpload?            p0=template%2Ftabs%2Ftab.html
            at http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:80:12
            at handleError (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:14858:17)
            at processQueue (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:12018:27)
            at http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:12034:27
            at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:13202:28)
            at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:13014:31)
            at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:13306:24)
            at done (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:8797:47)
            at completeRequest (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:9012:7)
            at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange                         (http://localhost:51491/Scripts/angular.js:8951:11)
```

Comment: You need to reference ui.bootstrap as a dependency in your main module `angular.module('detailapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])`

Comment: what is your problem. getting any errors?

Comment: I updated the console errors

Comment: Exactly what is the point of your TabsDemoCtrl? None of its members are being utilised for anything. What output are you getting and why do you believe it isn't correct?

Comment: Well if it implement correctly I should see 3 tab all clickable to switch to different content right? But it doesnt show no matter I initiate the controller or remove all the ng-controller

Answer (score 1):

So I find the error first, the boostrap download in nuget page doesnt work You have to use the other one

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
```

Such as this
Then initial your Controller in

```
 angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.tabs = [
         { title: 'tab1', content: 'Justified content' },
         { title: 'tab2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true },
         { title: 'tab3', content: 'Dynamic content 3', }
        ];

    });
```